# Volume Integral Discriminant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If I want to find $V(R)$, $R=\{(a,b,c) \in (0,1) \times (0,1) \times (0,1)\}: \frac{b^2}{4ac} \ge 1\},$    why is not just $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{4ac}}^{1}db\,da\,dc = \frac{1}{9}?$$

Comment: It is.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @martini, I don't get the same answer when I integrate over $b$ last. In this case you would have to split into two integrals in order to get something that is convergent.